# Retrieve Wamp "Index of /" localhost homepage to browse through directories

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I'm running WAMP on Windows 10. I had an old computer where I was running WAMP on Windows 8, and the WAMP localhost homepage used to be a tree-structure list of the files:

[image]

Which seems fine; I can browse through directories and see their contents.

Now the WAMP localhost homepage is a larger page with links to the tools, projects, etc.

[image]

However, when I try to browse through any specific parent folder (with many other subfolders of projects) from a link in "Your Projects", it fails. I get a "404 Not Found - The requested URL /my-site/ was not found on this server." error.

I don´t understand why it's different now, and I'm wondering how can I get the old WAMP localhost homepage?

Comment: The wampsever homepage should always have shown unless you delete the `\wamp\www\index.php`

Comment: You really need to create Virtual Hosts for each of yrou projects see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618 for how to do that or use the `Ajouter un Virtual Hosts` link and follow the instructions

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe, but the localhost page was not the same, and I tried deleting the index.php file but I got the 404 error

Comment: If you delete the `\wamp\index.php` you should get a view like your first image. **So what else have you changed**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just reinstalled WAMP server on my new computer, although I never deleted the index.php file before and I could still browse through the directories without getting the "404 Not Found" error whenever there's no an index.html or index.php file.

Comment: Your first picture shows `index.php`has been renamed as `index.txt` thats pretty much like deleting it!?!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, actually that one is a screenshot I found on the internet to show how it was, but the only screenshot I made is the second picture :/

Comment: Create a Virtual Host for each project and use Explorer (_not iexplorer_) to browse folders

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue on windows 10 x64.
Solution is in /wamp64 or wamp /bin/apache/apache2xxx/conf/httpd.conf . Remove comment tag (#).

```
#LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

to

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

Then Restart Wamp server to load autoindex module.

If you want to work on apache default page www/index.php , you need change

`$suppress_localhost = True;`

to

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

Solution from: [WAMP "index of / " page not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338285/wamp-index-of-page-not-working/38370359#38370359)