# WAMP "index of / " page not working

Tags: apache

my os is Windows 10 x64 and i m using wamp64. I changed "Require all denied" to "Require all granted" in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf\httpd.conf and I changed vhost but still not showing "index of" pages. localhost only run set pages dir_module pages .

Comment: Please check services: Apache and MySQL is running?

Comment: Yes Apache and Mysql is running. Ex. localhost/phpmyadmin (root login) and localhost/mysite/test.php working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is in /wamp64 or wamp /bin/apache/apache2xxx/conf/httpd.conf . 
Remove comment tag (#).

```
#LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

to

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

Then Restart Wamp server to load autoindex module.